# Static function was declared but never referenced error

Tags: c, function, static, declaration, definition

For the following code in C:

**file.h**

```
// declaration of extern function
extern void extFunc();
```

**file.c**

```
#include "file.h"

// declaration of static function
static void localFunc(uint32_t const input);

// definition of static function
void localFunc(uint32_t const input)
{
   // do something
}

// definition of extern function
void extFunc()
{
  // do something
}
```

When I compile the above code for ARM ISA target, I get compiler error saying

> Error[Pe177]: function "localFunc" was declared but never referenced in C:\Users\admin\git\file.c

How to get rid of it ?

Comment: Remove `static` from the forward declaration of `extFunc` in `file.c`. And, remove `extern` from the forward declaration of `extFunc` in `file.h`. In fact, remove the line: `static void extFunc(uint32_t const input);` from `file.c`. It is wrong and conflicts with the forward declaration in `file.h`. You only need _one_ such declaration and `extern` is not needed, and, in this case, harmful.

Comment: There was actually a typo in code I shared above. I fixed the typo. But error persists

Comment: If you declare or define a function [or variable] with `static`, you _must_ call the function from another function within the _same_ `.c` file. Or, you must _use_ the variable. So, at the bottom, add (e.g.) `void another_function(void) { localFunc(0); }`

Answer (score 2):

> > Error[Pe177]: function "localFunc" was declared but never referenced in C:\Users\admin\git\file.c
>
> How to get rid of it ?

`localFunc()` is declared `static`.  This means that the version of that function appearing in `file.c` is not accessible by name from other translation units.  Your compiler is telling you that it is not accessed by name from the same translation unit either, and no pointer by which it could be called is exposed, so the function definitely is not called at all.  It is dead code.

Normally this kind of issue warrants a warning instead of an error, but perhaps your compiler is especially strict, or you have enabled an option turns warnings into errors, so as to force you to resolve all diagnostics that otherwise would be just warnings.  In any event, there are several possible solutions, but these are the most likely:

1. Delete `localFunc()` and its forward declaration from `file.c`, or comment them out, or suppress them via conditional compilation directives.  This assumes that it is intentional that they are going unused.
2. Insert live code that calls `localFunc()`.  This only makes sense if it was some kind of mistake that `localFunc()` was not being called within the translation unit already.